# Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(/: Unterminated group

Tags: javascript

I'm checking if my string has special characters to replace but for the following string I'm having the following problem

**String**

```
(Lot P Verdes)
```

**Function**

```
function retira_acentos(palavra) { 
    com_acento = 'áàãâäéèêëíìîïóòõôöúùûüçÁÀÃÂÄÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÓÒÕÖÔÚÙÛÜÇ'; 
    sem_acento = 'aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuucAAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUC'; 
    nova=''; 
    for(i=0;i<palavra.length;i++) { 
        if (com_acento.search(palavra.substr(i,1))>=0) { 
            nova+=sem_acento.substr(com_acento.search(palavra.substr(i,1)),1); 
        } 
        else { 
            nova+=palavra.substr(i,1); 
        } 
    } 
    return nova.toUpperCase(); 
}
```

**Error**

**line:** if (com_acento.search(palavra.substr(i,1))>=0)

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(/: Unterminated group**

Comment: `search` uses regular expressions, and if you feed it strings, it tries to automatically convert them into one. But `(` on its own is not a valid regular expression to begin with, because `(` has a special meaning in regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've stumbled across here is that `String#search` requires a `regexp` as input, you, however, seem to want to search for a string input, not a `regexp`. In that case, use `String#indexOf` instead.

Try changing these lines and see if it gives you the desired output:

```
    if (com_acento.indexOf(palavra.substr(i,1))>=0) { 
        nova+=sem_acento.substr(com_acento.indexOf(palavra.substr(i,1)),1); 
    }
```

Comment: Or `String#includes`.

Comment: @twhb Nope, includes returns a boolean but our friend here wants a number, as you can see in the middle line

Comment: @Ahmed Bajra Thank you very much, it worked. And I also understood now the reason for the error as explained.

Answer (score 0):

In regular expression, round parenthesis are used to define groups. In this case, the regex parser thinks that you opened a group but you forgot to close it.

You don't want to open a group, I guess. You just want to match the literal character.

To match literal characters, in javascript regex, you have two ways:

- Escape the character with the backslace: `\`. Example: `/\(/`
- Wrap your character in square brackets. Example: `[(]`

In your case, it would be preferrable to use the second approach, because it works with any character (even with the ones that don't need to be escaped) and works also with many characters.

So I advise you to change the parameter of `search` in this way:

```
search('['+palavra.substr(i,1)+']')
```